# Laravel setting Job as failed

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, laravel-queue, laravel-6.2

How do I flag/set a Job as Failed?

I'm using closure function to dispatch a job that calls on external API, and I'd like to manually set if the job is success or failure based on the API response.

Here's my code, I'm using a simple example instead of API calls.

```php
public function sendSMS( $numbers ) {

    dispatch(function () use ( $numbers ) {            
        $this->smsProcess($numbers, $this->note->content);
    });

}

public function smsProcess( $numbers, $message ) {

    $int = random_int( 1, 10 ) * random_int( 1, 10 );

    if ( $int < 50  ) {
        throw ValidationException::withMessages('Less than 50')->status(403);
    } else {
        throw ValidationException::withMessages('Greater than 50')->status(403);
    }
}
```

When The `sendSMS` function runs, I can see a pending Job for `smsProcess`

But when I run the `queue:work` the job is being `Processed` and did not fail,

So how do I manually trigger the Job as failed?

If I put some error code on `smsProcess` I can see the job is marked as `Failed` Due to php error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `Exception` class not the `ValidationException`

```php
public function smsProcess( $numbers, $message ) {

    $int = random_int( 1, 10 ) * random_int( 1, 10 );

    if ( $int < 50  ) {
        throw new \Exception('Less than 50');
    } else {
        throw new \Exception('Greater than 50');
    }
}
```